# Cannot ready property of undefined custom component

Tags: angular

I have a custom `<app-ibd-payment>` component. I'm using it in two places of the application, It works fine in one place but in another place, it throws the error:

```html
<app-ibd-payment-details [intermediaryBankInfo]="banks.intermediaryBankInfo"   
  *ngIf="banks.intermediaryBankInfo != null">
</app-ibd-payment-details>
```

> SupplierDetailsComponent.html:3676 ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'intermediaryBankInfo' of undefined at Object.eval [as updateDirectives] (SupplierDetailsComponent.html:3693)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This means that `banks` is undefined. You should add a check to your `*ngIf` to ensure you can call properties on it.

```html
<app-ibd-payment-details [intermediaryBankInfo]="banks.intermediaryBankInfo"   
  *ngIf="banks && banks.intermediaryBankInfo != null">
</app-ibd-payment-details>
```

If you are calling properties on `banks` elsewhere in your HTML, you would move the `banks` condition to a higher level.

```html
<ng-container *ngIf="banks">
  <h2>{{banks.title}}</h2>

  <app-ibd-payment-details [intermediaryBankInfo]="banks.intermediaryBankInfo"   
    *ngIf="banks.intermediaryBankInfo != null">
  </app-ibd-payment-details>
</ng-container>
```

If you're using Angular 9, you can use optional chaining by placing a `?` after the property that *may* be `null` or `undefined`.

```html
<app-ibd-payment-details [intermediaryBankInfo]="banks.intermediaryBankInfo"   
  *ngIf="banks?.intermediaryBankInfo != null">
</app-ibd-payment-details>
```

Answer (score 0):

you have to place the `*ngIf` towards `[intermediaryBankInfo]` input.
You need to validate the `banks` as well.

```html
<app-ibd-payment-details
    *ngIf="banks?.intermediaryBankInfo"
    [intermediaryBankInfo]="banks.intermediaryBankInfo">
</app-ibd-payment-details>
```